# Java - How do i run a loop until no more data is entered

Tags: java, loops

What i need to do is take in data from a file and run it through a loop, the amount can vary from 1 to 50. So i won't be able to put in a counter, i figure it maybe a do while loop...just don't know how to set it up.

```
out.printf("Schedule Report\n--------------\n");
    out.printf("First: %s\n", fname);
    out.printf("Last: %s\n\n", lname);
    out.printf("M  D    Y  Hr Mn Pd  Category   Description\n");
    out.printf("-  -    -  -- -- --  --------   -----------\n");

    do{
    out.printf("%-2d", month);
    out.printf("%-3d", day);
    out.printf("%-6d", year);
    out.printf("%-3d", hour);
    out.printf("%-3d", minute);
    out.printf("%4s", pd);
    out.printf("%-2s", category);
    out.printf("%-10s", description);
    amApp++;
    pmApp++;
    }while()
    out.printf("Summery\n-------\n");
    out.printf("AM appointments: %d", amApp);
    out.printf("PM appointments: %d", pmApp);
```

Comment: You can take a look at a templating engine like freemarker or velocity. It is made for that purpose.

Comment: Do you have an array or collection with the appointment information you want to loop over? You'll need one of those for looping.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/file.html) about how to read data from a file. I imagine each item is represented by a single line in your file. Then depending on the format of each item (I assume they have a fixed format) you can use the [split](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) method to get the tokens that you need to print. Some examples about how to parse strings with split can be found [here](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html)

Answer (score -1):

If you are dealing with an input stream from a file, you should be able to use the `hasNext()` function, as in:

```
while (in.hasNext()) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: im getting an error with that, do i need to declare anything above?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing how you're reading the data in from the file.  Most of the time you'd have a file reader that would allow you to create an input stream (typically named "in"), but I can't tell from your code.